# Only display Card payments

Tags: mysql, sql

I designed a till system about 6 years ago, and while the code is dismal and horrible to look at, it is still going and the cafe I designed it for has been using it all this time.

However, they have recently acquired a card machine, and so now when they want to view all the sales for the day they wnat to see cash vs card in two separate tables.

This is proving tricky and the SQL for it is stumping me - I can't get my head around it.

Here are the tables involved:

categories

```
+----+-------------------+---------+------------+
| id |       name        | display |     ts     |
+----+-------------------+---------+------------+
|  1 | Drinks            |       1 | 2016-10-14 |
|  2 | General Snacks    |       1 | 2016-10-14 |
|  3 | Lunch Options     |       1 | 2016-10-14 |
| 4  | Conference Drinks |       1 | 2016-10-14 |
+----+-------------------+---------+------------+
```

products

```
+----+-----------------+-------+------+-----+---------+------------+
| id |      name       | price | cost | cID | display |     ts     |
+----+-----------------+-------+------+-----+---------+------------+
|  1 | English Tea     |   0.6 | 0.09 |   1 |       1 | 2018-02-15 |
|  2 | Speciality Teas |   0.8 | 0.17 |   1 |       1 | 2018-02-15 |
|  3 | Crisps          |   0.6 | 0.41 |   3 |       1 | 2018-02-15 |
|  4 | Chocolate Bar   |   0.6 |  0.5 |   3 |       1 | 2018-02-15 |
+----+-----------------+-------+------+-----+---------+------------+
```

receipts

```
+----+-----+-----+----------+------------+
| id | oID | pID | quantity |     ts     |
+----+-----+-----+----------+------------+
|  1 |   1 |  26 |        1 | 2013-11-21 |
|  2 |   2 |   6 |        2 | 2013-11-21 |
|  3 |   3 |   2 |        1 | 2013-11-21 |
|  4 |   4 |   3 |        1 | 2013-11-21 |
+----+-----+-----+----------+------------+
```

sales

```
+----+-------+----------+------+------+--------+------------+
| id | total | tendered | flag | card | userID |     ts     |
+----+-------+----------+------+------+--------+------------+
|  1 |     1 |        1 |    0 |    0 |      4 | 2013-11-21 |
|  2 |     2 |        2 |    0 |    0 |      4 | 2013-11-21 |
|  3 |   0.6 |      0.6 |    0 |    0 |      4 | 2013-11-21 |
|  4 |   0.6 |      0.6 |    0 |    0 |      4 | 2013-11-21 |
+----+-------+----------+------+------+--------+------------+
```

Please bear in mind that I wrote this a long time ago and I'm aware that its not perfect.   Just to explain the above, `oID` stands for `orderID` but really should be `salesID` and links to the sales table ID, and `pID` stands for `productID` and is a foreign key linking to the `products` table. Similarily, `cID` is really `categoryID`.

Okay So the cafe manager had requested a table that looks like the following:

```
+---------------+-----+------+-------+------------+-----------+
| Drinks        | Qty | Cost | Price | Cost-Total | Qty-total |
+---------------+-----+------+-------+------------+-----------+
| Juice Carton  | 2   | 33p  | 60p   | 66p        | £1.20     |
| Filter Coffee | 11  | 20p  | 80p   | £2.20      | £8.80     |
| Sub Total     | 13  |      |       | £2.86      | £10.00    |
| Grand Total   | 13  |      |       | £2.86      | £10.00    |
+---------------+-----+------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

Which has been fine, I've used the following SQL statement to produce this:

```
SELECT 
categories.name AS category, products.name, pID, 
(SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM receipts s WHERE s.pID = r.pID AND DATE(s.ts) = CURDATE()) AS quantity, 
products.price,
products.cost 
FROM receipts r 
LEFT JOIN products ON r.pID = products.id 
LEFT JOIN categories ON products.cID = categories.id 
WHERE DATE(r.ts) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY r.pID ORDER BY categories.name;
```

However now I need to display two tables, one for card and one for cash.  Now the card payments are marked in the `sales` table with a `1` in the card column.  So I tried writing this:

```
SELECT 
categories.name AS category, products.name, pID, 
(SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM receipts s WHERE s.pID = r.pID AND DATE(s.ts) = CURDATE()) AS quantity, 
products.price,
products.cost 
FROM receipts r 

LEFT JOIN products ON r.pID = products.id 
LEFT JOIN sales x on r.oID = x.id 
LEFT JOIN categories ON products.cID = categories.id 

WHERE DATE(r.ts) = CURDATE() AND x.card = 1 
GROUP BY r.pID ORDER BY categories.name;
```

However it is just displaying the same data as the first query.  I know where the problem is - its in the embedded SELECT statement (`AS quantity`), as I'm not specifying in there whether its a card payment or a cash payement.  I thought that just by adding `x.card = 1` a the end would do it, but evidentally not.

Can anyone help me fix this SQL problem? How can I get the card condition into the embedded SQL, as it is retrieving from receipts and receipts does not hold information as to wether its a card payment or not?

I'm lost as to how to proceed really.  All help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using outer joins? Aren't the foreign keys not enforced? (MyISAM)

Comment: The problem seems to be simple to solve and you got it already. That's exactly what I would do. It must be something else. Can you add an example in www.sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: @TheImpaler Its not simple, thats just as far as I've gotten.  I can't put the condition into the embedded SQL statement

Comment: It would be great if you can add a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In it's basic form:

`SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE card = 1`

Will display just the card payments

This will give you any sales from today:

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
    categories,
    products,
    sales,
    reciepts,
  LEFT JOIN
    products ON reciepts.pID
    sales ON reciepts.oID
    categories ON products.cID
  WHERE DATE(s.ts) = CURDATE() 
    AND sales.card = 1
```

`

So what you have there is correct. It's something else you are missing...

From what I can see so far you haven't selected the sales table which could be your issue.
Have you tried running the code in SQL management studio and seeing what the result is?

Comment: .... I was not aware that I could `SELECT FROM ` multiple tables at once? Is that a thing? I've never seen that done!

Comment: I would not recommend this syntax. It's not SQL standard and I have never seen it before.

Comment: You can indeed. I don't personally reccomend it if you're selecting specific columns from each table as it gets a bit messy but for demonstration purposes or selecting everything from the tables I don't see why it's an issue.

Comment: Hmm it would appear that this isn't MySQL compatible, Which is a shame because I liked how succinct it was.

Comment: I've just looked into it and it definitely seems that it's compatible with MySQL.
Baring in mind if you're selecting specific values you will need to specify the columns you want the data from... You may get clearer explanations from:
https://stackanswers.net/questions/mysql-select-two-tables-then-merge-results
Here: https://stackanswers.net/questions/select-multiple-tables-mysql
Or here:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/165846
All of which use MySQL :)